Registering both HTTP and gRPC ports in Eureka with Micronaut
I am trying to register both HTTP and gRPC ports in Eureka simultaneously using Micronaut. According to the documentation Micronaut gRPC Documentation, it should be possible, but I am facing issues with the registration of the gRPC port.(https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-grpc/latest/guide/index.html)
Here are the relevant parts of my configuration:
Eureka Server Configuration:
spring:
  application:
    name: MyEureka
server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: "http://localhost:8761/eureka"
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false

Micronaut Application Configuration:
eureka:
  client:
    registration:
      enabled: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: "http://localhost:${EUREKA_PORT:8761}/eureka"
      
flyway:
  enabled: true
  datasources:
    default:
      enabled: true

netty:
  default: 
    allocator:
      max-order: 3

jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 10000
        show_sql: true
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: update
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true 
        generate_statistics: true 

micronaut:
  application:
    name: cls-refusal
  router:
    static-resources:
      swagger:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger
        mapping: /swagger/**  
      swagger-ui:
        paths: classpath:META-INF/swagger/views/swagger-ui
        mapping: /swagger-ui/**
  server:
    max-request-size: 10485760
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 10485760
  security:
    enabled: true
    intercept-url-map:
      - pattern: /swagger/**  
        access:
          - isAnonymous()
      - pattern: /swagger-ui/**
        access:
          - isAnonymous()     

grpc:
  server:
    port: 1408
    instance-id: 'cls-refusal-grpc'

The logs show that both services are being registered:
enter image description here
I have verified that port 1408 is open and being used by my application. However, only the HTTP service is visible in the Eureka UI, and the gRPC service does not appear.
enter image description here
Also, the console shows that the port 1408 is already in use when the application starts.
enter image description here
What could be the reason my gRPC service is not appearing in the Eureka UI? How can I ensure both my HTTP and gRPC services are registered and visible in Eureka?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
